# Installation failure of coreOS

Tags: coreos, deis

I am trying to install CoreOS on VirtualBox and I have **coreos_production_iso_image**.
I followed the [link](https://deis.com/blog/2015/coreos-on-virtualbox/) to install it.

I am stuck at installation part. When I ran `sudo coreos-install -d /dev/sda -C stable -c cloud_config.yml` command, the installation stuck at that point and after long time it gives `exit 1` as an error message.

So I used `-v` option with `coreos-install` command, so it tries to download (wget) file from the [URL](http://stable.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/899.17.0/coreos_production_image.bin.bz2).

When I run separate `wget` command (without any options) with that URL, it downloaded that CoreOS file that means proxy doesn't block that URL but when I run `coreos-install` command it stuck at that point.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you created a `cloud_config`? Did you follow CoreOS's volume management scheme?

Comment: yes. I have created cloud_config file with following content.
#cloud-config
users:
- name: suraj
  passwd: $1$yxV9YDKT$s.fAj5dlFyrPwrH0xAQJy/
  groups:
  - sudo
  - docker



No. i didnt followed coreOS's volume management scheme.

Comment: I have done a CoreOS install for K8s following documentation from CoreOS but using private ip https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html